# Simple 555 on/off oscillator

Tags: 555

I have heard many people talking about how useful and simple the 555 timer chip is, yet I still cannot find a simple, easy method of creating a circuit that oscillates on and off every hour or so using this chip. Does anybody have a simple circuit for this?

Comment: I've heard a hammer is a good tool to fix stuff. But I can't find an easy method to fix my hand watch using a hammer.

Comment: An hour with a 555 is not realistic.  It starts getting iffy way before that.  You might run it at a much higher rate and divide the pulse rate down to get one pulse per hour, but the takes more than just the 555.  At that point, you might as well program a little microprocessor.  It will be smaller and more accurate.

Comment: for a 50% duty cycle , the simplest solution is a CD4060 timer binary counter. Use gates if you want a different duty cycle. Then faster clocks are used with long counter chains.  Cap leakage RC =T limits the long term usefulness of any CMOS clock.

Comment: Cough cough *crystal with frequency divider* cough cough

Answer (score -5, accepted):

[image: Astable 555]
 Hi, 
look at this simple schematic. It's one of the first results on Google images... Use some math to calculate the values for C and R.

Comment: Have you run the calculations for a one hour pulse rate?  Didn't think so.

Comment: He said one hour "or so", this schematic could still be useful because he doesn't know how to use the ne555

Comment: Could you put a link to the google images result? My wifi won't let me view any images on this site.

Comment: @redwolf10105 here: http://www.nutsvolts.com/magazine/article/555-astable-circuits

Comment: Since this is an accepted answer I would ask the OP to share a design based on it and satisfying the question..

Comment: @redwolf10105 obviously this circuit has his limits. You can't make it oscillate with 1 hour period with precision. But you can make it oscillate at a shorter period and feed the output to a counter. Example : for 1 minute of period, you can use a 6 bit counter and count to up to 60

Comment: Could it run at about 15 minutes?

Comment: Yes, but it will never be exact and stable.

Comment: Instead of an aluminum electrolytic, would using a different type (e.g. ceramic or tantalum) as C3 improve the time accuracy **at all**?

Answer (score 2):

One *great* circuit for this sort of thing is a tiny little microcontroller with a trivial program loop. At the risk of starting a flame war, I think maybe the 555's utility, in modern times, has been overtaken by the advent of low-cost, readily-available, easy-to-program, programmable devices.

Perhaps the appeal of the 555 is its special-purpose and "programmable" through the use of discrete external components. You could just as well use a microcontroller with a couple of analog inputs and set its timing parameters with voltage dividers. Surely this is more intuitive than using RLC-networked feedback circuits to get the desired effects?

Comment: I thing it's easier to use a 555 rather than a µC. µC needs external crystal in order a have a accurate clock, code the µC (easy but take more time than calculate RLC component)

Comment: I dislike microcontrollers, so I would prefer to use the 555 chip.

Comment: @redwolf10105 no problem, we can agree to disagree :-). I just wanted to register this as an answer for those who might not be so disinclined.

Comment: @M.Ferru - any microcontroller with an internal RC oscillator is still going be orders of magnitude more accurate than whatever comes out of a 555 with normal components necessary for a 1 hour period.

Comment: @brhans Is that because of the % error of components?

Comment: @brhans, I do not need accuracy for the application that I am using this for.